# How to extract phone number & email id from a string using Python Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to extract phone number and email id from a string using python regex and getting errors.

Please help me out with this.

```
txt = '''Saturday, February 6, 2021 at 9:00 AM – 1:00 PM CST4 days from now · 9–21°C Partly CloudypinBraeswood Farmers Market5401 S Braeswood Blvd, 26096Show MapHide MapFarmers Market+1 913-620-5318info@bighome25.comGet DirectionsDetailsSouthwest Farmers Market located in the heart of City. Fresh farmed produce, pasture raised eggs, organically fed poultry, locally farmed honey, grass fed beef, fresh prepared gourmet foods, and delicious food trucks.Vendor Inquiries - info@bighome25.comFoodKid FriendlyFarmers market'''
```

I want the phone to be: `+1 913-620-5318` and email: `info@bighome25.com`

```
phone = [x if (bool(re.search(r'+\d{1}\s| |\.\d{3}\s|-|\.\d{3}\s|-|\.\d{4}', x)) == True) else "" for x in txt]
```

Comment: Why those  `|`???

Comment: For space separator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
(\+\d\s*\d(?:-?\d)+)([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/k2dvxf/1/)

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -?                       '-' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )+                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w.-]+                  any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '.', '-' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @                        '@'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w.-]+                  any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '.', '-' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\w.-]+                  any character of: word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '.', '-' (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]{2,6}               any character of: 'a' to 'z' (between 2
                             and 6 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##ZVLBbtNAEL3nK0Y52Y1t2U5jkUqopakCCEWqFMQF97Dxju1V7V0zuyZyERL/wI9w672f0h8J4xCEgNOM3r43s/NmusHVRs8PB9V2hhwQTiadcA5Jw0ugqZfPcpnbs1x6lxfhZS79me99zPdReDe7OkV@yaNT7p9xKsKHuy9pkH31p5NGaeRK061wPUkxBLDGHfWCBsgCSOM0AeFgeRHH8GoDz9@@QzLmtxtYbd@fAysslGRa0GYPT4@wZEqaPP1Ywa0g1wywakwvh07paxJo98ZIWAtqkSxsBN2jW5zHCWzhz/N181ly6yxeZtuaq25E90ZJHOPfylkCy2QeZmkcLubJC6VLc7VTVW1aTBdRYdrX6OBGERZOGW1v0AnV2K3pXb1H6/75BzSmEA4lKA2uRqiRBwBTwkq5IYI1oa2hHCUSOjKyLzCATlj2DYGEsoxjVdkADFVCq0I0PH45sk3fOGJrxw5H8FcV3iwyWpGw9kjcIZYB2zl26gg7QQxWpme2g5K94eJCS5DYqEKZ3h5BcNQX9zb6gFoagrf6U69IoYUQ/rdkzYJ3infADC2b4bcH7dGD6aQVrqhZy8eFUam05A97p4vjAfha/ElHSjvvxPQPh58)**:

```py
import re

pattern = r"(\+\d\s*\d(?:-?\d)+)([\w.-]+@[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w.-]+)*\.[a-z]{2,6})"
line = "Saturday, February 6, 2021 at 9:00 AM – 1:00 PM CST4 days from now · 9–21°C Partly CloudypinBraeswood Farmers Market5401 S Braeswood Blvd, 26096Show MapHide MapFarmers Market+1 913-620-5318info@bighome25.comGet DirectionsDetailsSouthwest Farmers Market located in the heart of City. Fresh farmed produce, pasture raised eggs, organically fed poultry, locally farmed honey, grass fed beef, fresh prepared gourmet foods, and delicious food trucks.Vendor Inquiries - info@bighome25.comFoodKid FriendlyFarmers market"
matches = re.findall(pattern, line)
print(matches)
```

**Results**: `[('+1 913-620-5318', 'info@bighome25.com')]`

Comment: Thank you. Working perfectly fine and thank you once again for the clear explanation.